# Enterprise library handlingInstanceId

Tags: .net, exception

can i get handlingInstanceId without using custom handlers (i'm using standard handlers).

Comment: the set of people able to answer your question might be small; if you could elaborate a bit, you likely see more answers ..

Comment: if you want answers, you'd better give more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ReplaceHandler, you can actually put the handlingInstanceID in your custom error message:

```
<exceptionHandling>
  <exceptionPolicies>
    <add name="ReplacingException">
      <exceptionTypes>
        <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
          <exceptionHandlers>
            <add name="Replace Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ReplaceHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"
              exceptionMessage="An application error occurred and has been logged with error code: {handlingInstanceID}"
              exceptionMessageResourceName="" exceptionMessageResourceType=""
              replaceExceptionType="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          </exceptionHandlers>
        </add>
      </exceptionTypes>
    </add>
  </exceptionPolicies>
</exceptionHandling>
```